# Are the Paris Catacombs currently open for visiting?

Tags: paris, museums, history

I'm heading to Paris in a week's time (24th May) and the catacombs are at the top of my "places to visit list". However the [official site](http://www.catacombes.paris.fr/en/homepage-catacombs-official-website) says that the catacombs are closed for technical reasons until further notice. I haven't been able to find any other sources for this though, and am wondering if maybe the website hasn't been updated.

Are there any other definitive sources out there, corroborating the official site on whether the catacombs are currently closed?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As a matter of fact, they just have been reopened. The Musée Carnavalet, the museum in charge of the catacombs, announced on their [Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10152032021041548&set=a.387642531547.173182.159737906547&type=1&theater) one hour ago:

> Bonne nouvelle !
>
> Les Catacombes sont de nouveau ouvertes au public. Nous vous souhaitons un agréable après-midi

Which translates to: "Good news! The catacombs are now again open to the public. We wish you a good afternoon."

Comment: Fantastic! my hunch was right! Thanks for that

Answer (score 14):

It depends what you are talking about.

The "Ossuaire Municipal" where bones from thousands of people are stored just reopened according to [their Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/Carnavalet).
The [official site](http://www.catacombes.paris.fr/) is still saying it is closed but official stuff in France tend to be a tad slow.

Parisian people also use the word *Catacombes* for the [whole network of former quarries and other tunnels under Paris](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carri%C3%A8res_souterraines_de_Paris) (280 km).
This is closed to the public, except for the said *Ossuaire*.